# Expire time of ClaimsIdentity shorter than defined

Tags: c#, owin, claims-based-identity

I use ClaimsIdentity on my web site to identify my users.

I have set its `ExpireTimeSpan` to one hour but in fact it expire on about 15 minutes. I don't understand why...

web.config :

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="Web.AppStart" />
</appSettings>
```

AppStart :

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder builder)
{
    builder.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
        SlidingExpiration = true,
        LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/LogOff"),               
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
    });
}
```

User authentication :

```
internal static void SetCurrentUSer(UserModel user, HttpContextBase context)
{
    IList<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Login),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user)),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.IsAdministrator ? nameof(Profiles.Administrator) : nameof(Profiles.Player))
    };

    context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie));
}
```

All works fine, ClaimsPrincipal is set as well but the expire time never go to one hour.

Edit : I forgot to say I use asp.net MVC

Comment: Show us full code for `Startup.Auth.cs` - answer may be there

Comment: I don't have one... I launched my project at the beginning without claims identity, I managed all by myself and I rework some weeks ago to this way. So you think problem can be here ?

Comment: Do you have `SecurityStampValidator` referenced anywhere?

Comment: No, any of this. When I decided to use owin, I created by my own the `AppStart.cs` in the App_Start folder and referenced it in the web.config

Comment: Ok then, my answer/solution would be irrelevant then.

Comment: Is the browser closed in the meantime? These aren't persistent cookies. The browser may also drop them if too many other cookies are written.